# How can I get the context in doFinally or doOnCancel with reactor?

Tags: java, java-8, spring-webflux, project-reactor, reactive

I'm trying to get a value that I have in the context, I canot figure out how can I do that, any idea?, example:

```
 return mono
        .doFinally(signalType -> how??? )
        .doOnEach(signal -> { 
               ... signal.getContext();
               ...
            }) -> is ok I got the context
        .subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put("key", "foo"));
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider using [`Mono#deferWithContext`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#deferWithContext-java.util.function.Function-):

```java
return Mono
    .deferWithContext(ctx -> {
        mono.doFinally(signalType -> handleSignal(ctx, signalType))
            .doOnEach(...)
    })
    // later...
    .subscriberContext(ctx -> ctx.put("key", "foo"));
```